# Apache HttpClient - NTLM : 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm

I'm using Apache HttpClient version 4.5.3 to get some piece of information from a webservice (Microsoft-IIS/8.5).

Therfore NTLM authentication is required. But I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error at the end of this process although everything seems working well (sending messagetype1, receiving challenge, sending messagetype3).

Below the code and thanks if you could give some help to solve this error.

```
String workstation = "someurl.com";
String domain ="DOMBIN";
String userName = "KSY5989";

String soapMessage ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"https://tempuri.org/\">"+
        "<soapenv:Header/>"+ 
        "<soapenv:Body>"+
        "<tem:GetPass>"+
            "<tem:PasswordWSRequest>"+
                "<tem:UserName>user658</tem:UserName>"+
                "<tem:Address>someurl.com</tem:Address>"+
                "<tem:ConnectionTimeout>60</tem:ConnectionTimeout>"+
            "</tem:PasswordWSRequest>"+
        "</tem:GetPass>"+
        "</soapenv:Body>"+
        "</soapenv:Envelope>";


SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
         .custom()
         //FIXME to contain real trust store
         .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustStrategy() {
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

         })
         .build();

Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry2 = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
        .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory())
        .build();

NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(userName, password, workstation, domain);

CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();             
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry2).setSSLContext(sslContext).setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build()){

    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("someurl.net", 5489, "https");

    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("/TRWebService/v1.1/trib.asmx");

    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "https://tempuri.org/GetPassword");

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(soapMessage, "UTF-8");
    stringEntity.setChunked(true);
    httppost.setEntity(stringEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, httppost, context);
}
```

Comment: since the HTTP 500 response code indicates a server-side error, it would probably be easier to track this down on the web service side (find out what the server-side error is), if you have access to that.

Comment: I don't think it's a server-side error because with another program written in Ruby, everything works well. I don't have acces to the sever

Comment: It sounds like you are sending incorrect input, and the server is encountering a problem with it  - that's exactly what the 500 response means. I suggest comparing what you send to the server to what the Ruby app is sending.

Comment: I have already compared them but nothing seems realy different

Answer (score -2, accepted):

problem solved thanks to SaopUI which directed me to the cause of this problem.